# Why is the binary shift required when extracting lo and hi words from a DWORD?

Tags: c++, c

First off sorry about the title, I didn't want to make it too long or confusing. If someone can help me make it more general as this situation probably applies to any kind of bit mask operation.

[The following code is run in Windows (so it's little endian)]

If I have a DWORD (unsigned long) and a WORD (unsigned short) and I'd like to extract the low order and high order words from the double word why can't I just do this?

```
DWORD t = 0xAAAABBBB;
WORD loWord = t & 0x0000FFFF;
WORD hiWord = t & 0xFFFF0000;
```

For loWord I get the proper answer 0xBBBB for hiWord I just get 0 (see the full listing of the program at the end for printout of the result)

I've looked up how a Windows macro does it HIWORD(_dw) and what it does is just shift to the right by two bytes and then does the AND operation like so

`DWORD t= 0xAAAABBBB;
 WORD hiWord = (t >> 16) & 0xFFFF;`

But what I'm not understanding is if we shift to the right by two bytes why do we now need to perform an AND operation as well? And why is the shift even required, why doesn't my original code work as expected?

To illustrate why I'm confused about the shift followed by an AND, this is how I imagine the shift to work:

```
0x AA AA BB BB  >> 16  -> 0x 00 00 AA AA
```

so doing `0x 00 00 AA AA & 0x00 00 FF FF` would be pointless in my mind? What am I missing?

Also to be more exact the macro first casts the DWORD to a pointer then it shifts, like so (this is the exact macro)

```
#define HIWORD(_dw)     ((WORD)((((DWORD_PTR)(_dw)) >> 16) & 0xffff))
```

Can someone explain to me the purpose of the pointer cast? I tried with and without one and the results are the same.

This is an actual short program I used during the test to illustrate the issue in full:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


int main()
{
    DWORD t = 0xAAAABBBB;
    WORD loWord = t & 0x0000FFFF;
    WORD hiWordNoShift = t & 0xFFFF0000;
    WORD hiWordShift = (t >> 16) & 0xFFFF;

    cout << "t: " << std::hex << t << endl;
    cout << "hi (no shift): " << std::hex << hiWordNoShift << endl;
    cout << "hi (shift): " << std::hex << hiWordShift << endl;
    cout << "lo: " << std::hex << loWord << endl;



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The results are:

```
t: aaaabbbb
hi (no shift): 0
hi (shift): aaaa
lo: bbbb
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Think a little... The result of `0xAAAABBBB & 0xFFFF0000` is `0xAAAA0000`. Now how would you get those ***upper*** 16 bits into a 16-bit type like `WORD`? If you just do plain assignment the compiler will pick the 16 ***lower*** bits.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right, that makes sense. I changed the loWord and hiWord variables to DWORD type and now it's working as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Note: endianness isn’t a feature of the OS. It’s a feature of the processor architecture (though Windows always sets the CPU to little median if it’s run on a bi-endian system). Also shifting works differently on a signed and unsigned number so to be sure an AND can be used.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Right, thanks I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude

Also can you please explain to me the purpose of doing an AND after the shift and the purpose of casting to a pointer prior to shifting?

Comment: Note that the `HIWORD()` macro is universal. It should work on any machine. For example, in my Windows `DWORD_PTR` is an unsigned 64-bit integer

Comment: @Sergey so it just upcasts to a larger size container? But why?

Comment: The `AND` is there in case `t` is signed.  In this case, the high word will be all `1`s after the shift if `t` is negative.

Comment: @PaulSanders ah, right the negative is marked by the leading one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is so because `HIWORD()` should be universal and should be adopted to the size of the CPU registers.

On 64bit targets the general registers (like `RAX`) are 64bit registers and the size of `DWORD_PTR` is also 64bit.
On 32bit targets the general registers (like `EAX`) are 32bit registers and the size of `DWORD_PTR` is also 32bit.

So the compiler can generate more optimal code.